# What is the best practice for writing Authorization to limit developer error?

Tags: security, authorization

We have an application with built in authorization that executes queries against a database to return a report. The built in authorization limits what the users can see or access.

The issue is, if a new developer, or even a senior developer forgets to implement authorization, the report will default to returning everything.

Is there a better way to handle this issue or a standard practice that can help prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Make the authorization pessimistic.  It doesn't allow anything by default, and you have to explicitly grant permissions for it to work.  Forgetting = nothing is allowed to access it.

Comment: What prevents them from writing "select * from ...." to run the report? It would bypass our authorization and pull data directly.

Comment: That's a good question.  Normally you'd have a single point where all modules would request access.  I don't really know how your application is set up, but probably one of the first steps would need to be to lock down the report so that can't happen